# Save interactive shiny doc as pdf using knitr/Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I created an interactive doc (i.e., one embedded with functional Shiny apps) using R markdown / knitr in RStudio.

**Is there any way to "save" this interactive document as a pdf?**

Obviously, I know the shiny apps will no longer be functional if saved as a pdf. However, ideally I'd like an image showing the app in the pdf.

Is there a quick way to do this? (For example, some code chunk command that perhaps outputs a shiny app as a frozen image instead of a fully functional app)?

Comment: Save the MD file option in the YAML and then render MD output as pdf?

Comment: My concern is that LateX will do the pdf rendering and may not handle the HTML very well.  The other option is to render the HTML and print as a PDF in chrome.

Comment: @RyanMorton good idea, thanks, but that approach has lead to 2 issues: 1, the paging isn't smart enough not to cut off pictures/text between page breaks and 2, I don't get the formatting associated with the knit.pdf approach (e.g., font, coloring, spacing etc.).